# using multiple paramters in a min and max method

Tags: java

I am trying to put multiple numbers into a min and max method. I know that in a min and max method only two methods are allowed. However, I have more than two numbers and I don't have a clue what I'm doing.

This code is also on reply.it:

```
int age5 = 75;
int age6 = 62;
int age7 = 89; 
int age8 = 90;
int age9 = 101;
int youngestAge = Math.min()
int oldestAge = Math.max()
```

Comment: `Math.min(Math.min(age5, age6), age7)` or make your own.

Comment: thank you so much. I'm not quite sure why there is a math.min in the parantheses though?

Comment: It's a nested method call. It is calling `min` and finding the smallest number between two of the elements, and then the result of that is passed to the outer call to `min` and compared to `age7`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#min--

Answer (score 2):

You could use a loop

```
    int[] age = {75, 62, 89, 90, 101};
    int youngestAge = age[0];
    int oldestAge = age[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < age.length; i++) {
      youngestAge = Math.min(youngestAge, age[i]);
      oldestAge = Math.max(oldestAge, age[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(youngestAge+ " " + oldestAge);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) is a feature that allow methods to receive N params. So you can write a method with it that can receive a indefinite number of ages and returns the smaller one:

```
public int smallerNumber(int... numbers) {
    int smallerNumber = 0;
    int previousVerified = numbers[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        smallerNumber = Math.min(numbers[i], numbers[i-1]);
        if(previousVerified <= smallerNumber)
            smallerNumber = previousVerified;
        else
            previousVerified = smallerNumber;
    }
    return smallerNumber;
}
```

Calling this:

`smallerNumber(65, 654, 7, 3, 77, 2, 34, 6, 8);`

Returns this: `2`.

Answer (score 0):

With JDK 8+ you can use streams

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    int min = IntStream.of(75, 62, 89, 90, 101).min().getAsInt();
    int max = IntStream.of(75, 62, 89, 90, 101).max().getAsInt();
}
```

And another example with summary statistics

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    final IntSummaryStatistics s = IntStream.of(75, 62, 89, 90, 101).summaryStatistics();

    System.out.println(s.getMin());
    System.out.println(s.getMax());
}
```